# http component can't connect to proxy

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpcomponents

I'm trying to connect to a website through a proxy, but I'm getting an error

```
Error Code: 407 Proxy Authentication Required. Forefront TMG requires authorization to fulfill the request. Access to the Web Proxy filter is denied. (12209)
```

My code is very close to the example that apache provides, https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/examples.html (see the proxy authentication example). I'm definitely doing something wrong with authentication, but...what?

```
 HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost("http-proxy", 80);
    HttpHost target = new HttpHost(url, 80);
    CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
    credsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, new UsernamePasswordCredentials(user,password));


try (CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().setDefaultCredentialsProvider(new SystemDefaultCredentialsProvider()).build()) {

RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom().setProxy(proxy).build();
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("/basic-auth/user/passwd");
httpget.setConfig(config);

HttpResponse response = client.execute(target, httpget);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you are setting `new SystemDefaultCredentialsProvider()` when you are building the HTTP client. I guess you intention was to set `credsProvider`, to which you have just added proxy user and password.